# Recyclerview loading same data in a loop

Tags: java, android, api, pagination, reddit

The problem that I am facing is that whenever the recyclerview reaches the bottom of the list it loads the same data instead of the next Reddit page. In the AsyncTask I pass the String variable "after" which is needed to page using the Reddit API. What I want to happen and I believe should work is that when the page reloads add the String "after" to the url and populate the gallery with the next pages images. But from what I have implemented this seems to only load the same data over in loop. What seems to be incorrect here what am I doing wrong.

RedditParser.java

```
public List<DesktopItems> fetchItems(String after)
{
    List<DesktopItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    int counter = count + 25;

    try
    {
        String url = Uri.parse("https://www.reddit.com/r/battlestations/hot.json")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("?count", String.valueOf(counter))
                .appendQueryParameter("&after", after)
                .build()
                .toString();
        String jsonString = getUrlString(url);
        Log.i(TAG, "Received JSON: " + jsonString);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        parseItems(items, jsonBody);
    } catch (JSONException je)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON", je);
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch items", ioe);
    }
    return items;
}

private void parseItems(List<DesktopItems> items, JSONObject jsonBody)
        throws IOException, JSONException
{
    DesktopItems di1 = new DesktopItems();
    JSONObject dataPost = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data");
    di1.setAfter(dataPost.getString("after"));
    items.add(di1);
    JSONArray childPost = dataPost.getJSONArray("children");
    for (int i = 0; i < childPost.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject dataPost2 = childPost.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
        DesktopItems di2 = new DesktopItems();
        di2.setThumbnail(dataPost2.getString("thumbnail"));
        di2.setAuthor(dataPost2.getString("author"));
        di2.setPermalink(dataPost2.getString("permalink"));
        di2.setTitle(dataPost2.getString("title"));
        di2.setDomain(dataPost2.getString("domain"));

        JSONObject previewPost = dataPost2.getJSONObject("preview");
        JSONArray imagesPost = previewPost.getJSONArray("images");
        for (int y = 0; y < imagesPost.length(); y++)
        {
            if (!Objects.equals(di2.getDomain(), "self.battlestations"))
            {
                JSONObject sourcePost = imagesPost.getJSONObject(y).getJSONObject("source");
                di2.setUrl(sourcePost.getString("url"));
                items.add(di2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DesktopGalleryFragment.java

```
    public class DesktopGalleryFragment extends Fragment
{
    private RecyclerView mDesktopRecyclerView;
    private DesktopItems mItems = new DesktopItems();
    private List<DesktopItems> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean loading = true;
    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;
    private int count = 0;
    private String after;

    public static DesktopGalleryFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new DesktopGalleryFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        new FetchItemsTask().execute(after);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_desktop_gallery, container, false);
        mDesktopRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_desktop_gallery_recycler_view);

        final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        mDesktopRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mDesktopRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
            {
                DesktopItems desktopItems = new DesktopItems();
                after = desktopItems.getAfter();
                DesktopItems items = new DesktopItems();
                after = items.getAfter();
                PhotoAdapter adapter = (PhotoAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();
                int lastPostion = adapter.getLastBoundPosition();
                GridLayoutManager layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int loadBufferPosition = 1;
                if (lastPostion >= adapter.getItemCount() - layoutManager.getSpanCount() - loadBufferPosition)
                {
                    after = desktopItems.getAfter();
                    new FetchItemsTask().execute(after);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });


    private void setupAdapter()
    {
        if (isAdded())
        {
            mDesktopRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(mList));
        }
    }

    private class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoHolder>
    {
        private List<DesktopItems> mGalleryItems;
        private int lastBoundPosition;

        public int getLastBoundPosition()
        {
            return lastBoundPosition;
        }

        PhotoAdapter(List<DesktopItems> galleryItems)
        {
            mGalleryItems = galleryItems;
        }

        @Override
        public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new PhotoHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoHolder photoHolder, int position)
        {
            DesktopItems desktopItems = mGalleryItems.get(position);
            photoHolder.bindGalleryItem(desktopItems);
            lastBoundPosition = position;
            Log.i(TAG, "Last bound position is " + Integer.toString(lastBoundPosition));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return mGalleryItems.size();
        }
    }

    private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView mImageView;
        private DesktopItems mDesktopItems;

        PhotoHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_desktop_gallery_image);
        }

        void bindGalleryItem(DesktopItems desktopItems)
        {
            mDesktopItems = desktopItems;
            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(desktopItems.getUrl())
                    .into(mImageView);
        }
    }

    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<DesktopItems>>
    {
        @Override
        protected List<DesktopItems> doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            DesktopItems desktopItems = new DesktopItems();
            after = desktopItems.getAfter();
            return new RedditParser().fetchItems(after);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<DesktopItems> items)
        {

            if (count > 1)
            {
                mList.addAll(items);
                mDesktopRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else
            {
                mList = items;
                setupAdapter();
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_desktop_gallery.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_desktop_gallery_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: could you post xml layout?

Comment: @ScottS I added it, but I don't believe that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: try setting height to wrap content.

Comment: @ScottS Thank you for your answer, but I don't think you understand my problem.